# What damage can I cause by plunging a car battery section hole with wine cork?

Tags: battery

I have lost one of the plastic screws on my car battery.

Since they are not a part that is being sold, my options were limited to buying a new battery or to become creative.

I took a wine cork (from cork tree) plugged the hole, then made some turning and it seemed to grip on the grooves since it resisted being pulled out. So at least temporarily problem is solved with acid not spiling out under the hood while I am driving.

[image]

I am wondering about the longevity of this solution. What I am worried about is acid melting of some of the cork and that corkwood/acid solution mixing with battery acid and ruining the battery, or maybe getting on fire.

**What damage can I cause by plunging a car battery section hole with wine cork? What are my other options?**

Comment: This is a full bodied vintage with a real **kick**, I am picking up notes of  mild fruitiness and a strong metallic in your face first impression.  **It finishes very strong with a pronounced tannin's and an acidic  aftertaste**.

Comment: Can you? It appears you did. Should you? No.....

Comment: @GdD Hi, You are right, the title sounded silly. I changed it.

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind that a battery cap has a ventilation hole and you risk an explosion from a build-up in pressure, or the cork popping out and leaving the cell open.

Not all batteries need to be vented but you should check.

See if you can acquire a replacement cap from a dead battery at your local shop. If they are friendly they might say "just give the fitter a tip".

Comment: Hi Weather, thanks for the answer. I don't think those screws have wents, I have added the pic. Good idea with a local shops, much appreciated.

Comment: Some wine bottles have plastic stoppers now. That might be better than cork, unless it won't "take a thread": less chance of attack by the acid, or dropping fragments into the cell.